# How can I test an onClick line of a React component using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am learning React and I am currently trying Jest/testing. I am starting tests on a small project and I want to get 100% code coverage. Here's what I have.

component:

```
import React from 'react';

function Square(props) {
    const className = props.isWinningSquare ?
        "square winning-square" :
        "square";
    return (
        <button
            className={className}
            onClick={() => props.onClick()}
        >
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
}

export default Square
```

tests:

```
import React from 'react';
import Square from '../square';
import {create} from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('Square Simple Snapshot Test', () => {
    test('Testing square', () => {
        let tree = create(<Square />);
        expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})

describe('Square className is affected by isWinningSquare prop', () => {
    test('props.isWinningSquare is false, className should be "square"', () =>{
        let tree = create(<Square isWinningSquare={false} />);

        expect(tree.root.findByType('button').props.className).toEqual('square');
    }),
    test('props.isWinningSquare is true, className should be "square winning-square"', () =>{
        let tree = create(<Square isWinningSquare={true} />);

        expect(tree.root.findByType('button').props.className).toEqual('square winning-square');
    })

})
```

The line indicated as "uncovered" is

```
onClick={() => props.onClick()}
```

What is the best way to test this line? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use a [Mock Function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions)

```
test('props.onClick is called when button is clicked', () =>{
  const fn = jest.fn();
  let tree = create(<Square onClick={fn} />);
  // Simulate button click
  const button = tree.root.findByType('button'):
  button.props.onClick()
  // Verify callback is invoked
  expect(fn.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Also, for what it's worth, in your component you can assign the `onClick` handler straight to the prop i.e.

```
<button
  className={className}
  onClick={props.onClick}
>
```

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. And thank you for the extra tip!

Answer (score 0):

Simply target the element and call its handler:

```js
tree.root.findByType('button').props.onClick();
```